# JDBC Connection concurrency suffety

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, fork-join

I want create multhi-threading part of program (with GUI) for load data from very large DB table (over 30kk rows) by using `Fork/Join Framework` and `RecursiveAction` class, because many little query's execute faster then one large, checked experimentally. 
For example every fork load 50 rows from needed 1000. Something like this:

```
class ForkLoader extends RecursiveAction{

    private static Connection con;
    private Map<Integer, Double> map; //In our case ConcurrentHashMap
    private final static int seqThreshold=50;
    private List<Integer> id; //List with id_field in DB table

    int start,end;

    {
        try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://some_ip/some_db","username", "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ForkLoader(Map<Integer, Double> map, List<Integer> id,int start, int end){
        this.map=map;
        this.start=start;
        this.end=end;
        this.id=id;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if((end-start)<seqThreshold){
            try {
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
                for(int i=start;i<end;i++){
                    String query="text of some query" + id.get(i);
                    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    map.put(id.get(i), /*some double form result set*/);
                }
                stmt.close();               
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            int middle=(start+end)/2;
            invokeAll(new  ForkLoader(map, id, start, middle), new  ForkLoader(map, id, middle,end));
        }
    }

}
```

Is it thread safety use one `static` connection for all forks? If you know better way to solve this task, show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this kind of applications do it with a Connection Pool, in this way every Thread can use one connection exclusively, and if you have more Threads than connection at the same time, the Threads that doesn't have a connection assigned must wait.

If you want a framework for implement Connection Pool you can check these:

- Apache Commons DBCP http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/
- C3PO http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/
- Apache jdbc-pool http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html (thanks to MRalwasser)

In the other hand maybe you want delegate all the Thread and connection management to an EJB container,  basically you can implement the same with EJBs and Connection Pool managed by some container, you can check the following containers:

- Apache TomEE http://tomee.apache.org/
- Oracle Glassfish https://glassfish.java.net/
- Apache OpenEJB if you want only the EJB container without the full Java EE platform

Comment: Better recommend apache's jdbc-pool (part of the tomcat project) which is far more advanced than the old dbcp.

Comment: Program is standalone, not servlet/applet

Comment: disable1992 you can use OpenEJB standalone, you don't need the web container

Answer (score 0):

In general, `java.sql.Connection` instances (JDBC connections) are not thread-safe; you should not use the same `Connection` object from multiple threads at the same time.

Create a separate `Connection` for each thread instead.

Comment: Important moment of Fork/Join. It not create amount of threads==amount of forks. It create only 2 threads if your computer has only two core.